# Car jerks when I accelerate hard

Tags: toyota, noise, crown

I am getting a loud thump and the car jerks when I accelerate suddenly from a rolling speed. Say when rolling at 80km - 120km. I am not sure if this would be a gearbox issue or something else. Has anyone else faced the same? It is a Toyota Crown 2010, with 184000km. I do not have the gearbox service records so I am afraid of servicing it now with the high mileage. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you press on the brakes (while stationary), then shift it from reverse to drive and back again, do you hear the thump?

Comment: I just tried this with the car on and handbrake on. There is no thump.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your responses. We checked the motor mount and they were in mint condition. I finally decided to bite the bullet and service the gearbox. Happy to say this went extremely well. No more thump and jerk at cruising speed.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the motor mounts for play in the rubber bushings or loss of support if the mount is hydraulic. If they have not been replaced yet, with the indicated mileage, they maybe worn out and need replacing.